# Cannot understand why perfect forwarding is not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to understand how perfect forwarding works but I cannot understand why the copy constructor is called in the code below

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:
    Something() = default;
    Something(__attribute__((unused)) const Something& other) {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
    }
    Something(__attribute__((unused)) Something&& other) {
        cout << "Move constructor called" << endl;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Something::print() called" << endl;
    }
};

void function_1(Something&& one) {
    cout << "version two called" << endl;
    Something inner{one};
    inner.print();
}
void function_1(const Something& one) {
    Something inner(one);
    inner.print();
}

template <typename... T>
void test_function(T&&... ts) {
    function_1(std::forward<T>(ts)...);
}

int main() {

    const Something some1 {Something()};

    test_function(some1);
    test_function(Something());

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output

```
Copy constructor called
Something::print() called
version two called
Copy constructor called
Something::print() called
```

Changing the code to include `std::move` in the rvalue reference works but I did not expect to need it.  When a reference is an rvalue reference the correct constructor should be called automatically right?  The correct reference is resolved but the wrong constructor is being called.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should be easy to figure out: just set a breakpoint on the constructor, and when you hit it, the backtrace will tell you how it gets called. This is one of the easiest issues that can be solved with a debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand how it gets called, but the wrong overload is being called!

Comment: What do you say that? You do know that you need to explicitly use std::move() in order to preserve the rvalue reference semantics, right?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not when it is an rvalue reference?  That would make move constructing way too explicit all the time

Comment: It is not explicit when you're truly passing an rvalue. But, here, it is not an rvalue. It is an rvalue reference. rvalue != rvalue reference. Look up what std::forward does. Its specialization for an rvalue reference explicitly uses std::move().

Comment: @SamVarshavchik could you explain this a little more please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An rvalue reference *binds* to rvalues.  It is not itself an rvalue, for it has a name.

But anything with a name at point of use is an lvalue by default, even rvalue references.  Your code could use `Something&& one` three times, and if the first use implicitly `move`s you would be screwed.

Instead, it is an lvalue at point of use (by default), and it binds to an rvalue.

When you want to signal you no longer require its state to persist, `std::move` it.

Perfect forwarding can be used to write both of your `function_1`s by putting a `std::forward<Blah>(blah)` at the point where you'd want to move from blah if it was an rvalue reference.

---

Now the above is full of lies, for there are xvalues prvalues lvalues etc -- the standard is more complex.  The use of a variable in return statements can turn a named value into an rvalue, for example.  But the basic rule of thumb is worth knowing: it has a name, it is an lvalue (except if explicitly casted, or expiring).

Comment: Could you explain "But anything with a name at point of use is an lvalue by default, even rvalue references. Your code could use Something&& one three times, and if the first use implicitly moves you would be screwed." a little more?  Sorry I am having a hard time understanding this...

Comment: @curious does `Something&& one` have a name?  Yes?  Then it is an lvalue.  Imagine you did `auto x=one; std::cout << one << one; return x;` -- which of those 3 should move?  Rvalues are things with no name (so *cannot* be reused), or things explicitly cast to rvalue (so programmers fault), or local values returned in simple return statement (super-NRVO).

Comment: Ohhh...  This is completely contradictory to my previously incorrect understanding!

Answer (score 1):

This code will call the copy ctor, not the move ctor.

```
void function_1(Something&& one) {
    cout << "version two called" << endl;
    Something inner{one};
    inner.print();
}
```

This code calls the move ctor.

```
void function_1(Something&& one) {
    cout << "version two called" << endl;
    Something inner{std::move(one)};
    inner.print();
}
```

The expression `one` is technically an l-value. It refers to an rvalue-reference. But to actually get the rvalue-reference you have to use `std::move`. Generally anything that has a name is an l-value. Unnamed temporaries, like your `Something()` expression in `main()`:

```
test_function(Something());
```

can be rvalue's and can invoke a move without using `std::move`.

Comment: But then why is the copy constructor being called?  I don't think I understand fully what exactly is going on.  `one` is an rvalue.  So then why would the rvalue constructor not be called?

Comment: What's happening is, `test_function(Something())` causes the `version two called` line. (At first line of the implementation of `function_1(Something &&)`). Then the copy occurs. At `Something inner{one};`. In `test_function(Something())` it is correctly matching that as an r-value reference, otherwise you wouldn't see `version two called`. It's only when `inner` is instantiated that you are getting the copy.

Comment: I would like to mark both answers as being correct but I unfortunately cannot do that.  I will upvote your answers to give you an equivalent point bonus!